# "does not name a type" err when trying to use pointer to function

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I want to make a sorting function with a custom comparator, and the function lies inside a class. At first I followed my lecturer's instruction, but it turned out to be wrong when it came to member function (pointer-to-member and pointer-to-function is 2 different pointers, and they can't be treated as the other). I followed the instruction showed here, but it wouldn't make any different
http://www.radmangames.com/programming/how-to-use-function-pointers-in-cplusplus

Here's my code:

```
class llistStudent
{
public:
    void sort_list(bool (*comparator)(int &, int &));
    void swapStudent(int& positionA, int& positionB);

    bool sort_name_ascending(int& positionA, int& positionB);
    bool (llistStudent::*name_ascending)(int &, int &) = &llistStudent::method;
    name_ascending = llistStudent::sort_name_ascending;
};
```

And how I use it:

```
sort_list(sort_name_ascending);
```

It says:

```
'name_ascending' does not name a type
```

Where did I go wrong? Thanks!
Edit: It was a typo when I was editing the code to post it here: `sort_name_ascending`!`

Comment: The line `name_ascending = llistStudent::sort_name_ascending` fails to provide any type for `name_ascending`, hence the error.

Comment: What do you want to do by the wrong line `name_ascending = llistStudent::sort_name_ascending;`?

Comment: I assume you want name_ascending to be a function pointer?!

A function pointer to a member function can not be called without a pointer to an object of that class, except the function is static.

Comment: If you want to initialize `name_ascending` to `sort_name_ascending`, why do you initialize it to `&llistStudent::method` on the previous line?

Comment: Where's the definition of `sort_GPA_ascending`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two problems:

1) `name_ascending = llistStudent::sort_name_ascending;` is illegal in class definition. You cannot just slap random code in class like that. You should place it in some method, probably constuctor or make it part of declarator.
To fix this simply initialize your function pointer in declaration (C++11 and later only):

```
bool (llistStudent::*name_ascending)(int &, int &) = &llistStudent::sort_name_ascending;
```

2) `sort_list(sort_GPA_ascending);` is not going to work. `sort_list` expect parameter of type `bool (*)(int &, int &)`, and `name_ascending` has type `bool (llistStudent::*)(int &, int &)`

To fix this we need to know if your sorting function should have access to the class internals. If it should not (as it appears from your usecase), you should make it `static` and adjust pointer type accordingly:

```
static bool sort_name_ascending(int& positionA, int& positionB);
bool (*name_ascending)(int &, int &) = &llistStudent::sort_name_ascending;
```

Otherwise, you need to change type of `sort_list` argument to `bool (llistStudent::*)(int &, int &)`. Notice that member function pointers should be called on class instance (in your case it is probably `*this`).

Comment: The answer will be more useful if you can suggest how to fix the problems.

Comment: thanks! but how to use it? how do I call the function I passed into sort_list()?